# s3へのpythonを使った大きいサイズのfileを大量にuploadする方法

Tags: python, amazon-s3

s3へpythonを使って、１GBから５GBのファイルを100個単位でuploadしたいのですが、boto3で試してみたところ、uploadはされるのですが、3mbくらいのファイルがuploadされます。
どのようにすれば良いでしょう？？

Comment: このあたりの記事が参考になるのでは？ [Python: upload large files S3 fast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50105094/9014308), [teasherm/s3_multipart_upload.py](https://gist.github.com/teasherm/bb73f21ed2f3b46bc1c2ca48ec2c1cf5), [AWS S3 MultiPart Upload with Python and Boto3](https://medium.com/@niyazi_erd/aws-s3-multipart-upload-with-python-and-boto3-9d2a0ef9b085)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ファイルを確認してみるとなぜか大量の小さいサイズのファイルがたくさんありました。それを消去すれば大丈夫でした。誤認でした。すみません。